# Create round edges of progress spinner in material angular

Tags: angular, spinner, progress

I am using progress spinner from material angular in angular 4.
In my case, i need the spinner edge to be rounded like the one in the image attached. Can't figure out how to do that, as i am a bit less experienced working with svg.
  I have created this spinner, https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiEqI.png 
while i need this one
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV0Rs.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was easy, I just needed to add a path style property - strokeLineCap and set its value to 'round'

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering how to do it. Here is how: `.mat-progress-spinner circle {
  stroke-linecap: round;
}`